# re-parenting to screen two processes joined by pipe

Tags: linux, gnu-screen, pipe, background-process, tmux

Let's say in a PuTTY connection I start

```sh
mysqldump --host host1 --databases db1 db2 db3 | mysql
```

which creates two processes: `mysqldump` with PID 5800 and `mysql` with PID 5801. Is it possible to let the running processes continue execution when I want to close PuTTY and still be able to get back to them later?

I found some answers around here that deal with a single process and how to use `reptyr` to re-parent it to `screen`, but my concern is how to deal with my two processes that run in parallel.

Comment: That question is about one single process, mine is about two processes that use a pipe and that is actually my biggest concern as I don't want to break the communication between the two (yes, I understand it's actually unidirectional).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leave your busy session running.

Open another fresh session.

Use `tmux` so that app will persist even if you close or lose your ssh connection. The `tmux` is similar to `screen`, arguably a bit better.

```
sudo apt install tmux
tmux
```

Now the crucial step, steal the terminal of the processes.

```
sudo apt install reptyr
ps uw    # find one of the PIDs to save, any will do
reptyr -T the_PID
```

I've noticed one **side effect** of the `reptyr -T` method. You also catch your old shell along the running apps. If you `exit` now, you return to original shell of tmux/screen. Use `exit` again and you're back to your login shell.

Answer (score 0):

## how to deal with two processes that run in parallel?

There is a lot of possible answer, using or not `screen`, `tmux` or tools, or running as background tasks, using separated log files...

### Running two process separatedly

You could use ***named fifo***:

```
mkfifo $HOME/mysqlFifo
```

Then run in two separated *terminal* console:

```
mysqldump --host host1 --databases db1 db2 db3 >$HOME/mysqlFifo
```

and in second window:

```
mysql <$HOME/mysqlFifo
```

Then let it run...

### I want to close PuTTY and still be able to get back to them later?

#### `screen` too

Some preparation:

```
cat >$HOME/mysqlScreenRc <<eof
screen -t dump mysqldump --host host1 --databases db1 db2 db3 >$HOME/mysqlFifo
screen -t mysql mysql <$HOME/mysqlFifo
eof
mkfifo $HOME/mysqlFifo
```

then

```
screen -S mysql -c $HOME/mysqlScreenRc
```

or

```
screen -dmS mysql -c $HOME/mysqlScreenRc
```

to let it run in background...

Then to connect and watch:

```
screen -r mysql
```

For ensuring screen stay open afte commands terminated, you could use `read` command:

```
cat >$HOME/mysqlScreenRc <<eof
screen -t dump sh -c 'mysqldump --host host1 --databases db1 db2 db3 >$HOME/mysqlFifo;read foo'
screen -t mysql sh -c 'mysql <$HOME/mysqlFifo;read foo'
eof
```

### But you could just run in background with separated logs:

```
nohup mysqldump --host host1 --databases db1 db2 db3 2>/somepath/mysqldump.err |
    mysql >/somepath/mysql.log 2>/somepath/mysql.err &
```

So you could close this console, then watch about files in `/somepath`...